# Return on Investment Probability Indicator

Tags: feature-request

Very often questions are posted to my favorite tags. I can tell from the user profile and quality of question that I'm wasting my time trying to answer the question.  Sure enough I'll go down the rabbit hole trying to do the right thing.  The user won't upvote or accept and if I'm lucky years later I get 1 or 2 up votes for the question.

It'd really be nice to have some ROI indicator to tell me if the question is worth my investment or not.  Conversely it'd be nice if this information was available to the user to guide them in how to better participate.

Comment: build your own userscript for that?

Comment: Might you elaborate on what indicators should how influence the scoring? And are you aware that instituting such a metric would probably decrease the metrics usefulness immediately?

Comment: Sounds familiar to the accept rate which used to be displayed and has since been removed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate

Comment: If someone can make a reasonably accurate ROI predictor (and not something that turns into a self fulfilling prophecy generator) that can handle social and human behavior, I have a few business proposals for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look at the user's profile and combine that with the terminology and language used in the post.

Poor language? Weird question? Absurd terminology that makes no sense? Skip the question, you're not likely to give an answer that makes you happy writing it and the asker happy accepting it. You're likely to get dragged into a discussion in the comments either under the question or your answer. Consider closing as unclear or too broad.

The same goes for users with more questions than answers. Just skip their questions, or look carefully and downvote and closevote where appropriate.

This evaluation is hard to program, you'll have to do it in your mind.

Comment: I was hoping to automate this with statistics rather then manual profiling.  It's clear I'm alone hear and what you suggest is what I do today.   It's very hard to close questions on my tags because so few people read the questions.

Answer (score 6):

> It'd really be nice to have some ROI indicator to tell me if the question is worth my investment or not.

This only makes sense if you're only here to gain fake internet points instead of being here to help people. If we all used some kind of "what's in it for me?" metric instead of just answering good questions, a lot of decent questions would go unanswered and site quality would suffer. (Remember, we all started out with 1 reputation, 0 questions, and 0 answers.)

> Conversely it'd be nice if this information was available to the user to guide them in how to better participate.

Isn't that already in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? There's nothing wrong with politely linking to those resources in a comment if you think you've helped out a n00b and they don't seem to know what to do next.

Comment: That's judgemental. I've been contributing on SO for years and there is nothing fake or insecure about my work here.  I want to focus my attention to users who will be engaged.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter What's judgemental? My answer, or your question? (Also, I didn't say anything about your contributions. The points are what's fake.)

Comment: Also, whatever metric was shown, would have to be a surrogate because the real thing cannot actually be measured. And thus askers will naturally game that score to get more attention, undermining its usefulness.

Comment: It seems a bit crass to dismiss SO rep as fake internet points in this scenario, since the user in question appears to use these as a metric of his effectiveness. Since the OP is a software consultant whose work coincides with his degree of usefulness on SO, having a way (even if it's not entirely accurate) to measure his output and see what is most valuable is a bit more important than it is with most users.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Where are you getting any of this information? This seems to be a way of grading other users to tell if they're a waste of time or not.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Okay, I think I see what you're saying. I was following the thinking that he runs SO like he'd run a personal business, and is trying to maximize the benefit provided by his work, but something like this does so arbitrarily and at the expense of many of the users he's trying to help. I certainly wish I could ignore some requests at work, and focus on the interesting or useful ones, but I have an obligation to help those who need it, not just who will help me the most, and this is even more important on SO.

Comment: Close. More like help those who can be helped.  It's kind of like screening prospective clients and weeding out the ones that will be problems. It's a better experience for all parties involved.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Why not just judge each question on its own merits? It shouldn't matter who's asking if it's a good question.

Comment: Well I did ask if the "the question" was worth...  Sure, it's a factor.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter You judge a question by what's in the question, not by what's in the asker's profile.

Comment: I did write "quality of question" in my question.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter You also wrote "user profile."

Comment: Ok, I'm done arguing with you.  I guess all those things people wrote about you on the internet are true.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter When there's a two day gap in a conversation, you don't have to announce that it's done. It was already done.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a "Acceptance rate" statistic on user profiles.
This number was the percentage of questions from this user, that had it's answers accepted.

This statistic was removed, because people were actively avoiding answering good questions from users that had a low acceptance ratio.

In other words, statistics like these don't improve the quality of the site's contents. It's unlikely something like this will be added again.